# retrieve the cardid of last card added to stripe customer

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have the following code for adding a card for a customer which works fine and follows stripes API. However I need to retrieve the cardid of the one I just entered. When creating a customer I can use the expand method, but not sure on the adding card method?

```
// Get the credit card details submitted by the form
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

// Add a Card
$cu = Stripe_Customer::retrieve( $consumerCCID );
$cu->cards->create(array("card" => $token));

$defcard = $cu->card->id;
$last4 = $cu->card->last4;
$cardtype = $cu->card->type;
$expmonth = $cu->card->exp_month;
$expyear = $cu->card->exp_year;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe's libraries return the modified or created object. If you want that object, simply don't discard it:

```
$new_card = $cu->cards->create(array("card" => $token));
```